# WOW (Windows on Windows) Running 32 bit apps on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit

If I am not mistaken, I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit at home with a 32 bit version of Office. In other words, 32 bit apps work on 64 bit versions of Windows just like 16 bit apps worked on Windows 95.

What is WOW emulation?

My manager is asking me if a Windows 32 VB6 app will work on 64 bit Windows 7.

Comment: Have you tried googling?

Comment: Never heard of it, genius.

Answer (score 4):

The app will work without any issues that are related to fact that it is a 32 bit application. 16 bit applications will have issues though.

[It is called WoW64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64)

Comment: Is WOW Emultation something that is automatically running on 64 bit Windows 7?

Comment: yes it is. (padding)

Answer (score 3):

Let's get to the core question:

> My manager is asking me if a Windows 32 VB6 app will work on 64 bit Windows 7.

The answer is "probably, but you can't be sure and you might have to make a few tweaks to your system".  *Most* apps that ran on XP-32bit will run on 7-64bit with no extra work.  There are rare exceptions where the 64bit instruction set causes problems.

Much more common are issues where rules from Windows XP are now more strictly enforced in 7.  For example, in Windows XP, standard users do not have write access to the program files folders, but so many users ran with administrator privileges a lot of developers got away with one here and never even knew it.  Windows 7 now does a better job of enforcing the same rule that always existed, but in so doing it can break some old apps.  Usually you can get around this particular rule by manually giving write permissions to the Users group for just the specific folder you need, but this is just one example.

But the main thing here is that it's unlikely to be the 64bit vs 32bit issue that's causing you problems.

Answer (score 1):

If you notice, on your 64-bit OS you have links for IE and IE-64bit in the Start menu.  By default you are running IE 32-bit.  The implication is that 32-bit apps run without issue on 64-bit versions of Windows 7.
While I'm sure there are some apps that have an issue, I've not seen a problem with a 32-bit app on Windows 7 64-bit